# In PHP, how can I ensure the script will continue running until finished even after the browser quit?

Tags: php

I have a heavy loop that takes some time to be finished (usually around 5 minutes).

It doesn't really require anything from the user except for actually running it.

What happens in PHP if the user closes the browser while it still waits for a response from the server?

And if as I'm worried - it stops the script from being executed (leading partial execution) - is it possible to avoid it and make PHP finish what it started at all times?

Comment: Move your heavy processing to an offline system. A cron is popular for this, but you can also use a job queue. It is probably possible to carry on processing after delivering a page to the user, but it is rather hacky.

Comment: You could create a database entry only via the frontend php. Then have a cron job on the server check in soem intervals if the flag is set - and then run the job on your server's shell.

Comment: @halfer I still want the user to initiate the process, as it requires user input. but I believe pce just found the solution

Comment: You can run background processes via cron and job managers in response to user actions. In the case of a cron, just set a flag that says "requires processing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ignore user abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [set_time_limit](http://php.net/set_time_limit) for the execution time of the script itself as functions or as a [ini](http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) setting.

Answer (score 0):

you can ensure using log file in following way

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<300000000;$i++)
    {
         /*you heavy code goes here*/
    }
    error_log($i. "counts occure",0);
    echo $i;
?>
```

Comment: but if a error, timeout or user abort occurs, the `error_log` will not get called, therefore one had to [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).